# can't find module 'graphframes' -- Jupyter

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, graphframes

I'm trying to install graphframes package following some instructions I have already read.

My first attempt was to do this in the command line:

```
 pyspark--packages graphframes:graphframes:0.5.0-spark2.1-s_2.11
```

This works perfectly and the download was successfully done in the machine.

However, when I try to import the package in my Jupyter notebook, it displays the error:

```
can't find module 'graphframes'
```

My first attempt is to copy the package folder /graphframes to the /site-packages, but I can not make it with a simple cp command.

I'm quite new using spark and I'm sure I'm missing some parts of the configuration...

Could you please help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No module named graphframes Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50286139/no-module-named-graphframes-jupyter-notebook)

Answer (score 0):

This was what worked for me.

Extract the contents of the `graphframes-xxx-xxx-xxx.jar` file. You should get something like

```
graphframes
 | -- examples
       |-- ...
 | -- __init__.py
 | -- ...
```

Zip up the entire folder (not just the contents) and name it whatever you want. We'll just call it `graphframes.zip`.

Then, run the pyspark shell with

```
pyspark --py-files graphframes.zip \
    --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.5.0-spark2.1-s_2.11
```

You may need to do

```
sc.addPyFile('graphframes.zip')
```

before

```
import graphframes
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to start jupyter with pyspark and graphframes is to start jupyter out from pyspark.

Just open your terminal and set the two environment variables and start `pyspark` with the graphframes package

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS=notebook
pyspark --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.6.0-spark2.3-s_2.11
```

the advantage of this is also that if you later on want to run your code via `spark-submit` you can use the same start command