# No module named graphframes Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, apache-spark, graphframes

I'm following [this](https://graphframes.github.io/quick-start.html) installation guide but have the following problem with using `graphframes`

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc =SparkContext()
!pyspark --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.5.0-spark2.1-s_2.11
from graphframes import *
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 from graphframes import *
>
> ImportError: No module named graphframes

I'm not sure wether it is possible to install package on the following way.
But I'll appreciate your advice and help.

Comment: This might help: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/61386/graphframes-with-pyspark.html?childToView=61468#comment-61468

Comment: Looks like a nice workaround. Definitely, try, but I guess there should be the more general solution.

Comment: scala> util.Properties.versionNumberString
res0: String = 2.12.4

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Good question!

Open up your bashrc file, and type `export SPARK_OPTS="--packages graphframes:graphframes:0.5.0-spark2.1-s_2.11"`. Once you saved your bashrc file, close it and type `source .bashrc`.

Finally, open up your notebook and type:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext()
sc.addPyFile('/home/username/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/graphframes-0.5.0-spark2.1-s_2.11.jar')
```

After that, you may able to run it.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using jupyter notebook in docker, trying to get graphframes working. First, I used the method in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35762809/2202107, I have:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
import os

SUBMIT_ARGS = "--packages graphframes:graphframes:0.7.0-spark2.4-s_2.11 pyspark-shell"
os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = SUBMIT_ARGS

conf = pyspark.SparkConf()
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)
print(sc._conf.getAll())
```

Then by following this issue, we finally are able to `import graphframes`: https://github.com/graphframes/graphframes/issues/172

```
import sys
pyfiles = str(sc.getConf().get(u'spark.submit.pyFiles')).split(',')
sys.path.extend(pyfiles)
from graphframes import *
```

Comment: Which is better than the answer by @Pranav A, since I don't need to go fiddle manually with paths.

Comment: Thank you! this worked for me -- can anyone help me understand what the commands here doing that make it work?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to start jupyter with pyspark and graphframes is to start jupyter out from pyspark.

Just open your terminal and set the two environment variables and start `pyspark` with the graphframes package

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS=notebook
pyspark --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.6.0-spark2.3-s_2.11
```

the advantage of this is also that if you later on want to run your code via `spark-submit` you can use the same start command

Answer (score 0):

I went through a long painful road to find a solution that works here.

I am working with the native jupyter server within VS code.  In there, I created a `.env` file:

```bash
SPARK_HOME=/home/adam/projects/graph-algorithms-book/spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 6g --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.8.2-spark3.2-s_2.12 pyspark-shell"
```

Then in my python notebook I have something that looks like the following:

```python
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from graphframes import *

from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('GraphFrames').getOrCreate()
```

You should see the code to print out and fetch the dependencies accordingly.  Something like this:

```
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/home/adam/projects/graph-algorithms-book/spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2/jars/ivy-2.5.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/adam/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/adam/.ivy2/jars
graphframes#graphframes added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-96a3a1f1-4ea4-4433-856b-042d0269ec1a;1.0
    confs: [default]
    found graphframes#graphframes;0.8.2-spark3.2-s_2.12 in spark-packages
    found org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.16 in central
:: resolution report :: resolve 174ms :: artifacts dl 8ms
    :: modules in use:
    graphframes#graphframes;0.8.2-spark3.2-s_2.12 from spark-packages in [default]
    org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.16 from central in [default]
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
    |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    |      default     |   2   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   2   |   0   |
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

after that I was able to create some code with the relationships:

```python
v = spark.createDataFrame([
  ("a", "Alice", 34),
  ("b", "Bob", 36),
  ("c", "Charlie", 30),
], ["id", "name", "age"])
```

It should work fine.  Just remember to align all your pyspark versions.  I had to install the proper versions of `graphframes` from a forked repo.  The PiPy install is behind on versions so I had to use the `PHPirates` repo to do the proper install.  Here the graphframes has been compiled for version `3.2.0` of `pyspark`.

```bash
pip install "git+https://github.com/PHPirates/graphframes.git@add-setup.py#egg=graphframes&subdirectory=python"
pip install pyspark==3.2.0
```