# ImportError: No module named 'graphframes' databricks

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azure-databricks, graphframes

I am trying to import graphframes in to my databricks notebook

```py
    from graphframes import *
```

but failed with following error message

> ImportError: No module named 'graphframes'

How can I add/import in to databricks notebook, any help appreciated.

Comment: have you install graphframes ? check this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50286139/no-module-named-graphframes-jupyter-notebook. Installation  https://pypi.org/project/graphframes/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** By default, "graphframes" is not installed on the databricks.

You need to install the package explicitly.

You can install the packages in different methods.

**Method1:**  Installing external packages using pip cmdlet.

**Syntax:** `%sh /databricks/python3/bin/pip install <packagename>`

```
%sh
/databricks/python3/bin/pip install graphframes
```

[image]

**Method2:** Using Databricks [library utilities](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#library-utilities)

**Syntax:**

```
dbutils.library.installPyPI("pypipackage", version="version", repo="repo", extras="extras")
dbutils.library.restartPython()  # Removes Python state, but some libraries might not work without calling this function
```

To install graphframes using databricks library utilities use the below command.

```
dbutils.library.installPyPI("graphframes")
```

[image]

Tried the examples available in this article [GraphFrames Documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/graph-analysis/graphframes/index.html).

**Notebook output:**

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`graphframes` is not default dependency with python. You should install this dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the graphframes module by opening your terminal and typing `pip install graphframes`