# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphframes'

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, graphframes

I want to run `graphframes` with `pyspark`.

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50404308/9500955) and follow its instruction but it doesn't work.

This is my code `hello_spark.py`:

```py
import pyspark

conf = pyspark.SparkConf().set("spark.driver.host", "127.0.0.1")
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(master="local", appName="myAppName", conf=conf)
sc.addPyFile("/opt/spark/jars/spark-graphx_2.12-3.0.2.jar")

from graphframes import *
```

When I run with this command:

```
spark-submit hello_spark.py
```

It returns this error:

```
from graphframes import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'graphframes'
```

This is my `.bashrc` config:

```
# For Spark setup
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark

export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/sbin

export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3

export SPARK_LOCAL_IP=localhost

export SPARK_OPTS="--packages graphframes:graphframes:0.8.1-spark3.0-s_2.12"
```

My version of `spark: 3.0.2`, `scala: 2.12.10`.

I installed `graphframes` with this command:

```
pyspark --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.8.1-spark3.0-s_2.12
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I use this command, it will works:

```
spark-submit hello_spark.py --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.8.1-spark3.0-s_2.12
```

And you should be noticed that you have to install some dependencies for `pyspark` like `numpy`:

```
File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/ml/param/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

So I just change the `PYSPARK_PYTHON` path to my `miniconda` environment.

```sh
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/home/username/miniconda3/envs/pyenv/bin/python
```

You can find your environment path by activating it and run `which` command:

```sh
(base) username@user:~$ conda activate pyenv
(pyenv) username@user:~$ which python
/home/username/miniconda3/envs/pyenv/bin/python
```